# asp.net measure page load time

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-load-time

I need to measure page load time in out asp.net project, so I get the time stamp in `Page_PreInit` method and in  `Page_Unload` method from the base page, but my problem is that these events are fired twice. How to avoid this behavior, given the fact the in some child classes in `Page_Load` event at some controls that have `runat=server`, the value may be changed from code(bind, index changed, etc)?

PS: I have to save the load time in a hidden field.

Comment: You simple use your browser tools to count the time there the delay time from the request to the get first byte

Comment: Not knowing what you're trying to achieve , but couldn't you simply check that the value is set in PreInit and not overwrite it and always overwrite it in Unload? Then you have the first set and the last set?

Comment: The load time from http response will be read by a 3rd party profiler installed on the web server and will insert it into a database and reports will be generated based on this value.

Comment: Maybe [glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) is what your are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Beside try to measure the time on server, you can measure the time using the browser tools, and here is an example.

We have two times that we measure, one is the delay up to the first byte, and the second is the delay to fully load the page.

So I write this code to simulate this delay.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
}
```

and on asp.net, simulate the page load as:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">    
</head><%Response.Flush();%>
<body>    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <% System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); %>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is how you can see that delays using the browser Network tools:

[image]
<sub>(source: [planethost.gr](http://www.planethost.gr/so/So002.gif))</sub>

Comment: I need to write the value inside a hidden field because this value will be read automatically by a 3rd party profiler and add the results in a database